# How can we limit the number of threads in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading

Say I want to download 10k biz 20 at a time, each in it's own thread.

How do I specify that the limit of thread is 20

Or is there a way to check number of running thread?

Comment: note: 20 threads/downloads on these devices is excessive.

Comment: NSURLConnection is limited to 6 concurrent downloads. Any HTTPD with a decent administrator is also likely to ban your IP.

Comment: Wasn't this question originally tagged iOS or iPhone? Changes the context considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use NSOperationQueue and set the max concurrent count to 20.

Comment: Decided to remove my downvote on this answer, and comment instead—though it currently won't let me change my vote. I downvoted this because while it gave the questioner what they were asking for, it seems like a bad idea for them to be doing this, due to the likelihood that 20 threads will be excessive. (I am pretty certain this was originally tagged iOS or iPhone, as presumably was Justin above.) Decided that if that is what they want, they deserve to get it!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Grand Central Disptch global queues... They will automatically limit the number of concurrent threads to what is going to be suitable for the current processor.

Without knowing what a "biz" is, or where and now you are "downloading" them, hard to be more specific.